# Set-OdbcDsn - Determine Property Values

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to configure properties of an existing ODBC DSN. Working example code:

```
$properties = @('server=myserver1', 'description=sql server 2008')
Set-OdbcDsn -Name 'TestDSN' -SetPropertyValue $properties -DsnType System
```

This works, `server` and `description` are valid input. My question is: how can I discover a list of properties `-SetPropertyValue` accepts? If I use:

```
Set-OdbcDsn -Name 'TestDSN' -SetPropertyValue = @('foobar=myserver2') -DsnType System
```

This does not work, for obvious reasons. It returns the error `Set-OdbcDsn : Invalid keyword-value pairs`

I checked [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/wdac/set-odbcdsn?view=win10-ps) powershell reference, but no help.

How can I find valid keyword names for `-SetPropertyValue`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google search led me [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/dsn-connection-string-attribute?view=sql-server-2017). It contains the two values you found to work, `server` & `description` AND it did not contain the value `foobar` which did not work.

Answer (score 0):

For your "TestDSN" you can see valid keywords in property "Attribute".
In this case it's "Description, Server, Regional, Database".

```
Get-OdbcDsn -Name TestDSN


Name       : TestDSN
DsnType    : System
Platform   : 32-bit
DriverName : SQL Server
Attribute  : {Description, Server, Regional, Database}
```